# Interface Builder does not recognize outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

It's been awhile since I've used Xcode and I resumed an old project I was working on awhile ago.  I created a new UITableViewCell subclass.  In my storyboard, I dragged a UITableViewCell onto my UITableView of my UIViewController.  I changed the type of the UITableViewCell to my subclass, but when I control + drag from the UITableViewCell subclass to the UITextField, it doesn't allow me to make the connection.

```
.h of my UITableViewCell custom subclass
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *titleTextField;
```

I must be going crazy because I thought this was something that just worked.  I saw in another UIViewController that there is a custom subclass for the UITableView when I worked on this project last.  I changed the subclass that was having the problem to that type of UITableViewCell subclass and I'm still not able to ctrl+drag to make the IBOutlet connection.  Am I missing something here?  Wasn't this something that always worked this way?  Is there something new I'm not aware of?  I tried using the assistant editor as well to drag it to the code, but that doesn't work either.  I went back to the UITableViewCell subclass that DOES have a connection already made from when I last worked on this, and I tried ctrl+dragging to the label again, and it doesn't bring up the menu on which outlet I want to connect to either.

Another thing that is weird, is when I'm trying to type the custom class of my UITableViewCell that is already created, even though I built my project, it doesn't autocomplete it in the Class field.  I'm not sure if my Xcode is having problems.  Also, I don't know if this matters, but in my UITableViewCell, I Have some standard UITableViewCells as well. Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: if it not auto completes in class field then also you have to type your class file name in to that field and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all I had to do for my class name to appear in the drop down was to quit Xcode and come back in.  I thought things like that would have been fixed in the IDE.

I found that I could still add the connections in the connections inspector.  I don't know why they removed the very easy ctrl+drag from the left hand side of the storyboard unless I'm missing something.